# Button icon being cut off from top and bottom

Tags: html, css, button

The top and bottom areas of my button are being cut off. It's allowing me only to have my icon be the same height as my button's text. I tried overflow hidden, I tried expanding the button padding.

[image]

HTML:

```
<div id="toprow">
    <div id="homeDiv">
        <a href="#"><button type="button" id="homeBtn"><span>HOME</span></button></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#homeDiv{
    float:left; margin-left:160px;}
a #homeBtn span{
    background:url(home.png) no-repeat;
    padding-left: 45px;
    background-position: 0px -10px;}

#homeBtn{
    font-size:1em;
    outline:none;
    background:none;
    border:none;
    cursor: pointer;
    }
```

Comment: Open up in chrome, inspect the element and start playing around with the css in the inspector.

Comment: Try using fontawesome icons, which will automatically adjusts. <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"> </i> HOME</a>

Comment: Check that a parent container of #homeDiv does not have "overflow:hidden;" set. It could also be a few levels up depending how nested this div is.

Answer (score 1):

Anchor tags are inline elements by default. You might try changing your link to display block or inline-block. The reason for this is inline elements are not affected by top and bottom padding. I can't remember off the top of my head but the same may be true for margin as well. `display: inline-block;` on the `<a>` tag

EDIT:
Sorry, didn't notice the span tag. So the `<span>` tag is inline as well. Since your using the image as a background the element is only fitting to the text size, so you might try Johannes suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

In this rule

```
a #homeBtn span{
    background:url(home.png) no-repeat;
    padding-left: 45px;
    background-position: 0px -10px;}
```

add: `background-size: contain;`

that should make the icon img just small enough to fit into its container.

EDIT / addition: Reset the backgound-position to 0px 0px, or to settings that cause a position you are satisfied with.

Comment: Thanks! But it's really small this way, tiny. Is there any way I can expand the container size and make it work?

Comment: well, you can add `height: 50px; width: 120px;`or whatever size you like to the `#homeBtn` rule.